# Неправильно отображается кириллица в vscode (почему то только с python). Знаки вопроса вместо символов

Tags: python, кодировка, visual-studio-code, utf-8

Выходные данные в консоли не нормальные русские символы, а ромбики со значками вопроса (ну или как я видел у других людей просто всякие символы непонятные). Менял кодировку файла UFT-8, и кодировку в VSCode, и сохранение в этой кодировке делал как везде пишут, но ничего не помогало(потому что все изначально стояло в utf-8). Нашел видео на ютубе мол менять надо на windows 1251, но это временный костыль, видео ни о чем. Но автору все равно спасибо.
Вариантов пока нет.

Answer (score 2):

Первый абзац вводный(просто вода). **Решение в следующем абзаце**.
Нашел в общем ответ в комментариях под одним из видео про 1251. Потратил уйму времени на чтение однотипных "поменяй справа внизу на utf-8", формата "if u are homeless just buy a house". В основном советы по кодировкам, какие бывают, как исправить, какие файлы, как комп, какие проги, какие языки воспринимают кодировки. КодировкаКодировкаКодировка. А решение оказалось очень простым, но естественно нигде о нем почти не говорят.

**Решение:** В системе в регион и язык ставим галочку на Бета-версии кодировки
Путь: параметры -> время и язык -> язык -> административные языковые параметры -> дополнительно/изменить язык системы -> ставим галочку напротив Бета-версия

[image: язык и время]

Comment: Не трогайте эту галку. Гимора будет потом вагон. У винды своеобразное понятие про unicode

Comment: и как же тогда иначе решить проблему кодировки в utf-8 ?

Answer (score 0):

Не надо никакие галки ставить!!!!
Элементарно, в settings.json меняем
code-runner.executorMap

"python": "python -u"

на
"python": "set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && py -u"